# Service with name'hz:impl:cacheService' not found

Tags: hazelcast, jcache

I am write my hazelcast prototype code. I encountered the following error when running the reader. Not sure what did I miss.

```
SEVERE: [host1]:5701 [dev] [3.7.3] Service with name'hz:impl:cacheService' not found!
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Service with name 'hz:impl:cacheService' not found!
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.getService(NodeEngineImpl.java:350)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.getService(Operation.java:239)
    at com.hazelcast.cache.impl.operation.PostJoinCacheOperation.run(PostJoinCacheOperation.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.PostJoinOperation.run(PostJoinOperation.java:93)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:181)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:375)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.run(OperationServiceImpl.java:267)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.runOperationOnCallingThread(OperationServiceImpl.java:262)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.FinalizeJoinOperation.runPostJoinOp(FinalizeJoinOperation.java:139)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.FinalizeJoinOperation.run(FinalizeJoinOperation.java:104)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:181)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:396)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:117)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:102)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Service with name 'hz:impl:cacheService' not found!
    ... 14 more
```

Here is my code

```
public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(“host1”).setEnabled(true);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(“host2”).setEnabled(true);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        IMap<String, DataDetail> mapCustomers = hz.getMap("customers");

        while (true) {
            mapCustomers.lock("Joe");
            try {
                System.out.println("Joe(R) => " + mapCustomers.get("Joe").getTimeStamp());
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } finally {
                mapCustomers.unlock("Joe");
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Writer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Config config = new Config();
         config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(“host1”).setEnabled(true);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(“host2”).setEnabled(true);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        IMap<String, DataDetail> mapCustomers = hz.getMap("customers");
        DataDetail od = new DataDetail ();
        od.setDataId(“X1”);
        od.setTimeStamp(0);
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
            mapCustomers.lock("Joe");
            try {
                mapCustomers.put("Joe", od);
                od.setTimeStamp(od.getTimeStamp() + 1);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                DataDetail localOd =  mapCustomers.get("Joe");
                System.out.println("Joe(W) => " + localOd.getTimeStamp());
            } finally {
                mapCustomers.unlock("Joe");
            }
        }

    }
}


public class DataDetail  implements DataSerializable {
    String dataId;
    Integer timeStamp;

    public DataDetail() {
    }

    public void setDataId(String dataId) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
    }

    public String getDataId() {
        return this.dataId;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Integer timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public Integer getTimeStamp() {
        return this.timeStamp;
    }

    public void writeData( ObjectDataOutput out ) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(dataId);
        out.writeInt(timeStamp);
    }

    public void readData( ObjectDataInput in ) throws IOException {
        dataId = in.readUTF();
        timeStamp = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the JCache API classes (JAR) to your classpath, otherwise the CacheService is not started.

Comment: So once JCacheAPI is in the classpath, HazelCast will use that as caching for the data it stores/fetches?

Comment: But my code doesnt use any Cache, why does it complain caching service is missing? Does it add caching feature for me internally?

Comment: Oh I see, yeah good question. Seems like the PostJoin expects the CacheService to be available. Let me forward this to engineering. Thanks for clarification, missed that point yesterday evening.

Comment: It appears some of your cluster members have JCache API on classpath while others don't. This is not supported at this moment. You either have to have JCache API on all members or you have to remove it completely. We just created an issue for your scenario: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/9301

Comment: Just curious, does caching fit my use case? My data source keeps changing which is why I was using Hazel Cast distributed map. It will be interesting I can stack caching on top of of Hazel Cast map. Any suggestion? Sample Code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jcache to connect to Hazelcast servers, you have to add `cache-api-1.1.0.jar` in the `lib` directory. After that, you have to show the jcache api jar when exporting `CLASSPATH` in the `start.sh`.

When the former `export CLASSPATH` expression in `start.sh`:

```
export CLASSPATH="$HAZELCAST_HOME/lib/hazelcast-all-3.9.3.jar"
```

after the edit:

```
export CLASSPATH="$HAZELCAST_HOME/lib/hazelcast-all-3.9.3.jar:$HAZELCAST_HOME/lib/cache-api-1.1.0.jar:$CLASSPATH/*"
```

Comment: Thumbed up as that is a more explanatory answer.